# Replace page no with custom string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

There is a string

```
http://www.ccdcdlmcc.sdc.smdc.,ms.cmcsjh?page=2$#$#L$JK#J$LK#J$
```

I want to replace the page number with a different string *"[pageno]"* (including square brackets),
so that my final string will be:

```
http://www.ccdcdlmcc.sdc.smdc.,ms.cmcsjh?page=[pageno]$#$#L$JK#J$LK#J$
```

I already tried it with *explode* and str_split($string), but no luck...  can it be done by a regular expression?

My main String`http://www.xyz.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A117332031%2Cn%3A!117333031%2Cn%3A118457031%2Cn%3A118458031&page=2&bbn=118457031&ie=UTF8&qid=1337146507` is

Comment: You're in luck if you have the pecl_http extension installed [CodePad](http://codepad.org/OM5hteGk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$str=preg_replace("/(\\?)(page)(=)(\\d+)/","?page=[pageno]",$yourstring);
```

Comment: Unknown modifier '(' [APP/controllers/tests_controller.php, line 61]

Comment: @IntekhabKhan This problem has been solved by the edit of harald. There are also a lot of unnecessary groups here `/\\?page=\\d+/` would work exactly the same (nah, better, because the values are not stored in backreferences). Maybe you are interested in a [brief regex introduction I wrote](http://wp.me/p2pTzU-4)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
<?php

$str = "http://www.ccdcdlmcc.sdc.smdc.,ms.cmcsjh?page=2$#$#L$JK#J$LK#J$";

echo preg_replace('/page=([0-9]+)/', 'page=[pageno]', $str);
?>
```

I do assume that the page number is a numeric value only. Otherwise you'll have to extend the [0-9] with [0-9a-zA-Z] and perhaps other characters you want to allow.